# How to merge / union table in SSIS with different key?

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

i've been learning ssis for 1 week and still get to know all the tools that are availables and now trying to do some exercise.
If  i have 3 tables with different keys but i wanted to join/merge/union them how to do that?
for example :

**FirstTable**

`+----+------+----------+-----+--+
| id | code |   Name   | qty |  |
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
|  1 | A001 | Computer |   2 |  |
|  2 | X001 | Disc     |   6 |  |
|  3 | Z002 | Mouse    |   4 |  |
+----+------+----------+-----+--+`

**SecondTable**

```
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
| id | code |   Name   | qty |  |
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
|  7 | P001 | Computer |   2 |  |
|  9 | O001 | Disc     |   6 |  |
|  4 | S002 | Mouse    |   4 |  |
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
```

**TableThree**

```
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
| id | code |   Name   | qty |  |
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
|  5 | K001 | Computer |   2 |  |
|  6 | J001 | Disc     |   6 |  |
|  8 | F002 | Mouse    |   4 |  |
+----+------+----------+-----+--+
```

So in this case they're all actually the same data, but maybe the first table was made in 2010, second table in 2011, third table 2014.
They just have the differences in their first character of their itemcode, and i wanted to join/merge/union the three of it. Still got no idea how to do that.
The only idea is maybe i used some fuzzy lookup?

Comment: `UNION` will help you for this kind of data.

Comment: Thankyou so much for replying!
So just using UNION ? is the data gonna be "double inserted"? since they have different id and code?

Comment: If the data are unique based on Id and ItemCode then you don't need to worry for data redundancy! so there is an option in SSIS to use `Merge Join` inside *DATA FLOW TASK* then use `FULL-OUTER` which will create same data as UNION.. Still It can have multiple solutions based on your data and exact requirement.. Please refer: https://www.resultdata.com/merging-options-with-ssis/

Comment: Okay thankyou, i'm really sorry for causing all the troubles. but Thankyou so much. I'm literlly newbie on it since it's the first time for me to use ssis.

Comment: No issues. please comment if you find any other difficulty in that.

Answer (score 0):

As a more scalable solution (assuming you could have more than 3 tables that need to be unioned), you could use a foreach (based on table names) with a single dataflow (sourced from a variable of each table) that run into the same destination.

This is a similar approach to when you have similar files that contain the same columns that need to be loaded into the same table.